# What does this regular expression do?

Tags: php, regex

What is the regex checking for?

```
/[a-z0-9]{1,3}\|.+?\|\d+/i
```

Answer (score 4):

Any character ( a to z and A to Z ) or digit occuring 1 to 3 time followed by a "|" followed by any symbol until the next "|" followed by any number of digits.

The `?` in `.+?` is a lazy / greedy match and matches till the next `|`.

The `i` flag at end is for the entire match being case-insensitive.

Sample matches:

```
abc|1avb|123
AbC|$%#$|0
```

Comment: And isn't the 'i' at the end so that it is case insensitive?

Comment: @George Kastrinis - yes....what is your question? I have included that in the explanation - note that I say "any character" not any "lower case"

Comment: You have explained the resulting match, not the regex.

Comment: @George Kastrinis Isn't the line `Any character or digit occuring 1 to 3 time followed by a "|" followed by any symbol until the next "|" followed by any number of digits.` explaining the regex? Ok, I have added explicit explanation.

Comment: "Any character" is wrong. It will only match any letter in the Unicode range 'a' to 'z' (or 'A' to 'Z'). It will not match, for instance, 'é', Greek letters, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Any sequence consisting of 1, 2, or 3 letters in the range 'a' to 'z' (inclusive, and in either case) or decimal digits, followed by the character '|', followed by any number of characters of any kind, followed by a '|', followed by any number of decimal digits.